# Node.js Cannot read property of undefined using JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to convert a js script to a node.js script. The JS script works fine, and managed to pull data from [this URL](http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/343/fixtures) and correctly use the information. However, when I try run it on Node.js, I get the error `"Cannot read property of 'fixtures' undefined."`I've added [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) to pull the data, however I'm not sure why it's now throwing an error.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Get Data
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
        } else {
        callback(status, xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

//Use Data
getJSON('http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/343/fixtures',
function(err, data) {
    if (err !== null) {
    console.log("   An error has occured.")
    } else {
    var latest;
    for(x = 0; data.fixtures[x].status !== "TIMED"; x++) {
        latest = data.fixtures[x].matchday - 1;
    }
}};
```

The error is thrown at the line `while(data.fixtures[x].status !== "TIMED")`, and the error is

```
for(x = 0; data.fixtures[x].status !== "TIMED"; x++) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixtures' of undefined
```

Please could you explain to me why JS can see the data and use it fine, but node.js sees the property to be undefined?

Many thanks.

EDIT: Removed legacy while loop that shouldn't have been there.

Comment: You have `data` in the code snippet, but `fbdata` in the error message. Maybe you mistyped the variable name?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you increment `x` and then reset it back to zero?

Comment: @mingos, good spot, but that was me just testing to see if Node didn't like data. Variable name is fine.

Comment: @Jamiec Actually, I told a lie in my previous comment. The while loop isn't needed in this code anymore.

Comment: Can we get the *actual* code you're using then?

Comment: Apologies, it's up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting that message is because the variable `data` in your callback *is* `undefined`. The reason it is so is that you are passing it that

```
callback(null, xhr.response); //<-- You should have used responseText
```

But even that will not solve the issue - it is text not json. So parse it

```
callback(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `response` property is part [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/), but `xmlhttprequest` only supports 1 at the moment:

> Note: This library currently conforms to XMLHttpRequest 1.

For this reason `xhr.response` will be `undefined`.

Only `xhr.responseText` will be set, and this is a string so you would need to add the parsing of json yourself.

```
if (status === 200) {
  try { // use a try block here in case the the response is not parseable
     callback(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
  } catch(e) {
     callback(e)
  }
} else {

  callback(status, xhr.response);
}
```

Comment: I will try implement this in a couple of minutes when I'm back on my machine. Thanks in advance!